# API access, shows in network tab request is made but no response

Tags: javascript, api

```
$.getJSON({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'https://api.willyweather.com.au/v2/MGI3NWY5MWYxYjIwNDYxNDNhYWM1NT/info/legal.json?platform=web',
  success: function(data) {
    window.onload.console.log(data.info);
  }
});
```

This works fine when input directly into the browser, but running this script I don't get a response.

It shows up in the network tab. 
EDIT: No "response" in the network tab but it shows up as a request.

I queried to the API dev and he says its designed to be server side? `jsonp` is not supported.

English was not his first language, so hopefully someone's experienced this before.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you're even running the code?

Comment: Yeah. Ill use a different open weather's API and itll work just fine

Comment: If you visit the URL in your browser, it says the parameters are incorrect.

Comment: Removed ?callback=? From the url. I was trying a few things and forgot to remove that part. Apologies

Comment: Everything cool then?

Comment: Negative. Problem is the same

Comment: Like they said, chances are you are unable to use this service's API.  Their documentation is offline, so that doesn't help either.

Comment: Comes back with a 400 response for me

Comment: I get 200 response (if only platform parameter is used), but there is no access control allow origin on the response so the browser blocks it

Comment: Hm, im also getting a 200 response. I've just realized the site asks for a URL for my website/app. Would this be relevant to my issue?